# Картинки по кириллическому адресу

Tags: java, android, изображения

Есть картинка расположенная по кириллическому адресу вида [http://вася-пупкин.бел/NAME.jpg](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD.%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB/NAME.jpg)
И когда я пытаюсь её загрузить при помощи Glide или Picasso то ничего не выходит, никакой реакции. Как можно декодировать URL в подходящий вид?
Сразу скажу что пробовал и не помогло:

```
Uri.encode(url)
IDN.toASCII(post.getImgUrl())
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode("текст_на_кириллице", "UTF-8"))`?

Comment: тоже пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод который поможет перевести адрес из кириллицы в [Punycode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

```
public static String convertUnicodeURLToAscii(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) return url;
    url = url.trim();
    // Handle international domains by detecting non-ascii and converting them to punycode
    boolean isAscii = CharMatcher.ASCII.matchesAllOf(url);
    if (!isAscii) {
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        boolean includeScheme = true;
        // URI needs a scheme to work properly with authority parsing
        if (uri.getScheme() == null) {
            uri = new URI("http://" + url);
            includeScheme = false;
        }
        String scheme = uri.getScheme() != null ? uri.getScheme() + "://" : null;
        String authority = uri.getRawAuthority() != null ? uri.getRawAuthority() : ""; // includes domain and port
        String path = uri.getRawPath() != null ? uri.getRawPath() : "";
        String queryString = uri.getRawQuery() != null ? "?" + uri.getRawQuery() : "";
        // Must convert domain to punycode separately from the path
        url = (includeScheme ? scheme : "") + IDN.toASCII(authority) + path + queryString;
        // Convert path from unicode to ascii encoding
        url = new URI(url).toASCIIString();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо было гуглить не "кириллический url", а "кириллический домен".
А конкретно вам требуется: "Конвертация IDN в Punycode". Алгоритма я сходу не нашёл, но полюбому уже должны быть какие-нить готовые либы.

Answer (score 0):

Кириллический адрес url надо декодировать. Попробуйте использовать **[этот инструмент](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)**. Или же что-то выберите из поиска **[cyrillic url decoder](https://www.google.se/search?q=cyrillic%20url%20decoder)**.